# How can i have conditional [formControl] directive?

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I have a REUSABLE component where i am passing some formControlName.
This child component for that reason implement control value aceessor

**toggle switcher TS**

```js
export class ToggleSwitchComponent extends BaseControlValueAccessor<boolean> implements OnInit {
    @Input() public formControlName: string;

constructor(@Optional() ngControl: NgControl) {
        super(ngControl);
    }

}
```

**toggle switcher HTML**

```html
 <input
            class="custom-control-input toggle-switcher"
            type="checkbox"
            [id]="uniqueId"
            [attr.disabled]="disabled ? '' : null"
            (change)="onToggleSwitchChange($event)"
            [checked]="bindValue"
            [formControl]="formControl"
        />
```

so when i use this component from outside sometimes i want to pass some formControlName sometimes not. For that reason i have @Optional flag in the constructor so when i don't pass it will not throw error.

so when i use my component

```html
<xecm-toggle-switch formControlName="canceled">
</xecm-toggle-switch>
```

everything works fine.

The problem is when i don't pass formControl

```html
<xecm-toggle-switch  [disabled]="item.disabled" [bindValue]="item.autoIncrement" (toggleSwitchEmitter)="toggleSwitchEmitter($event, index)">
</xecm-toggle-switch>
```

then my bindValue is not taken into consideration. Because the formControl is null

so my question is - when ngControl is null and formControlName is not provided how can i apply [formControl] on condition on my input ?

something like [formControl]='ifTrue ? formControlName : otherwise dont apply formControl'

Answer (score 0):

When using `ControlValueAccessor`, it's better to keep the inner template and implementation of the component isolated as possible. i.e. regardless of how we pass the value through to the component, we should always manage the internal state from one place.

In your case, we can either pass the value to the `checkbox` using the `checked` property or using CVA (formControl/formControlName/ngModel), regardless of how we receive it from the parent.

1. Control the `checkbox`'s value using the `checked` property:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-toggle-switch',
  // ...
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => ToggleSwitchComponent),
      multi: true,
    },
  ],
  template: `<input
    type="checkbox"
    (change)="onToggleSwitchChange($event)"
    [checked]="innerValue"
  />`,
})
export class ToggleSwitchComponent implements OnChanges, ControlValueAccessor {
  @Input() bindValue: boolean;
  @Output() toggleSwitchEmitter = new EventEmitter<boolean>();

  /** This is what we will use in the template, or any logic in the component class */
  innerValue: boolean;

  onChange: (value: boolean) => void;

  // 1) To handle the @Input change, we can use this hook, or use setter of the property directly.
  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    if (changes.bindValue) {
      this.innerValue = this.bindValue;
    }
  }

  writeValue(value): void {
    // 2) To handle the value once it comes through the CVA.
    this.innerValue = value;
  }

  registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
    this.onChange = fn;
  }

  // Other CVA's methods implementation
  // ...

  onToggleSwitchChange(value: boolean) {
    // Sync the value with the parent
    // Since we support receving the value using the CVA and @Input,
    // then we should send it back using the CVA' onChange(), and @Output.
    this.onChange(value);
    this.toggleSwitchEmitter.emit(value);
  }
}
```

OR

2. Control the `checkbox`'s value using `ControlValueAccessor`:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-toggle-switch',
  // ...
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => ToggleSwitchComponent),
      multi: true,
    },
  ],
  template: `<input
    type="checkbox"
    (change)="onToggleSwitchChange($event)"
    [formControl]="innerFormCtrl"
  />`,
})
export class ToggleSwitchComponent implements OnChanges, ControlValueAccessor {
  @Input() bindValue: boolean;
  @Output() toggleSwitchEmitter = new EventEmitter<boolean>();

  /** This is what we will use in the template, or any logic in the component class */
  innerFormCtrl = new FormControl<boolean>(false);

  onChange: (value: boolean) => void;

  // 1) To handle the @Input change, we can use this hook, or use setter of the property directly.
  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    if (changes.bindValue) {
      this.innerFormCtrl.setValue(this.bindValue);
    }
  }

  writeValue(value): void {
    // 2) To handle the value once it comes through the CVA.
    this.innerFormCtrl.setValue(value);
  }

  registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
    this.onChange = fn;
  }

  // Other CVA's methods implementation
  // ...

  onToggleSwitchChange(value: boolean) {
    // Sync the value with the parent
    // Since we support receving the value using the CVA and @Input,
    // then we should send it back using the CVA' onChange(), and @Output.
    this.onChange(value);
    this.toggleSwitchEmitter.emit(value);
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your comment,But i need both ways in my component to support reactive forms and template driven as i said to bind value in checked property. My question was hot to apply formControl on condition

Comment: I think there is no need to apply `formControl` on condition to achieve your goal! Instead, you can bind to it always, and then control how you will pass the value to it from both accessors: `@Input`(s) and CVA as mentioned in my answer. If you're trying to bind the `ngControl.control` directly in the child template, I recommend not doing that to keep your child component as isolated as possible. Anyway, if you still need that, you can use `*ngIf` to render the `input` with `control` if it's available, otherwise, render it without `control`.